# Unable to pull the results by passing input as xml path in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am just trying to pull the records bypassing the XML path in where the condition of SQL unfortunately I am unable to do.

**Note**: Pull the records bypassing input as salesteamid value. Please someone can help me to run the query without any failures.

**Query** :

```
SELECT * from activity where= ExtractValue('/ActivityId/Agent/Territory/SalesTeamId[contains(10669)]');
```

**XML**:

```
<Activity
    xmlns="urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3" RestrictionGroup="NONE"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="DiscussionActivityType" TransactionCode="I" CreatedOnDate="2019-11-21T16:04:29" UpdatedOnDate="2019-11-21T16:04:32" SourceCreatedByID="20303090" SourceCreatedByFirstName="Brandy" SourceCreatedByLastName="Nirider" SourceCreatedByRole="" SourceUpdatedByID="20303090" SourceUpdatedByFirstName="Brandy" SourceUpdatedByLastName="Nirider" SourceSystemCode="FSA" SystemOfRecordCode="FSA" RecordCompanyCode="AZN" SourceCountry="USA" SourceRegion="USA" SourceSystemGroup="VNA" SystemOfRecordGroup="VNA">
    <ActivityId>
        <ns2:ID
            xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2" SystemCode="VNA">a080P00001YZM7WQAX
        </ns2:ID>
    </ActivityId>
    <Agent>
        <EmployeeId>
            <ns2:ID
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2" SystemCode="EMPLID">20303090
            </ns2:ID>
        </EmployeeId>
        <Territory>
            <ns2:TerritoryId
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">
                <ns2:ID SystemCode="AZ">20070009</ns2:ID>
            </ns2:TerritoryId>
            <ns2:TerritoryCode
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">20070009
            </ns2:TerritoryCode>
            <ns2:Role
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">PSS
            </ns2:Role>
            <ns2:Description
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">Indianapolis C IN 2
            </ns2:Description>
            <ns2:SalesTeamId
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">
                <ns2:ID SystemCode="AZ">10669</ns2:ID>
            </ns2:SalesTeamId>
            <ns2:SalesTeamCode
                xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2">D_ALPHA
            </ns2:SalesTeamCode>
        </Territory>
    </Agent>
    <Customer>
        <AZCustomerMasterID SystemCode="AZ">58586509</AZCustomerMasterID>
        <SourceCustomerID SystemCode="NAVVA">001U000000pMTySIAW</SourceCustomerID>
        <CustomerType>HCP</CustomerType>
        <CustomerActivityRole>participant</CustomerActivityRole>
    </Customer>
    <ReferenceContent>
        <ReferenceName>Reported Adverse Reaction</ReferenceName>
        <ReferenceType>action</ReferenceType>
        <ReferenceId SystemCode="VNA">Reported Adverse Reaction</ReferenceId>
    </ReferenceContent>
    <StartDate>2019-11-21T16:03:00</StartDate>
    <EndDate>2019-11-21T16:03:00</EndDate>
    <Topic>
        <Name>BYDUREON BCISE</Name>
        <Product>
            <AZBrandId SystemCode="AZ">881574</AZBrandId>
            <AZProductId SystemCode="AZ">881574</AZProductId>
            <SourceProductId SystemCode=""/>
            <ReferenceProductId SystemCode=""/>
            <ProductName>BYDUREON BCISE</ProductName>
        </Product>
    </Topic>
    <ActivityAction>discussion</ActivityAction>
    <ActivityStatus>completed</ActivityStatus>
    <ActivityInitiatedBy>AstraZeneca agent</ActivityInitiatedBy>
    <ActivityOutcome>success with identified customer</ActivityOutcome>
    <CommunicationMode>in person</CommunicationMode>
    <LocationSetting>Selling</LocationSetting>
    <SourceValues>
        <Status>Submitted</Status>
        <SubStatus>Completed</SubStatus>
        <Applet>Actions</Applet>
        <Activity>Detail Only</Activity>
        <InteractionCategory>A_Selling (PSS)</InteractionCategory>
        <Type>Selling</Type>
    </SourceValues>
    <Priority>2</Priority>
    <DiscussionTool>N</DiscussionTool>
    <ActivityTypeCheck>DiscussionActivityType</ActivityTypeCheck>
</Activity>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with your query? Is this XML stored in a column of the `activity` table? Are you trying to extract information from the XML as columns or just return other columns of the `activity` table if the XML meets a certain condition?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give your expected output. As it is currently written, you do not describe how expect to be able to "pull the records bypassing the XML path in where the condition" so we do not know what you want and the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to extract information from the XML as columns or just return other columns of the activity table if the XML meets a certain condition

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to filter on an ID within the XML, you have an issue with syntax, you've supplied the root node as ActivityId instead of Activity, you aren't going down to the ID node, you're misusing `contains` - and that probably isn't what you want anyway; and you're ignoring the namespaces.

This will only find rows where the XML has a specific ID:

```
SELECT * from activity
where ExtractValue(xml,
  '/Activity/Agent/Territory/ns2:SalesTeamId/ns2:ID/text()',
  'xmlns="urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3" xmlns:ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2"'
  ) = 10669;
```

But ExtractValue has long been deprecated, so you should use XMLQuery instead. Or in this context it would probably make more sense to use XMLExists, with the value you want embeded:

```
SELECT * from activity
where XMLExists('
    declare default element namespace "urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3";
    declare namespace ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2";
    /Activity/Agent/Territory/ns2:SalesTeamId/ns2:ID[text()=10669]
  '
  passing xml
);
```

or perhaps more usefully supplied as an argument:

```
SELECT * from activity
where XMLExists('
    declare default element namespace "urn:astrazeneca:na:Activity:domain:3";
    declare namespace ns2="urn:astrazeneca:na:CommonTypes:domain:2";
    /Activity/Agent/Territory/ns2:SalesTeamId/ns2:ID[text()=$id]
  '
  passing xml, 10669 as "id"
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a3260cbf8d835b2611d913ae489cc5e4)

If you then want to extract specific data from the XML in matching rows then look at XMLQuery or XMLTable - but that's a separate issue.